# NAnt or MSBuild, which one should I use in an svn environment?

Tags: msbuild, nant

I have a C# project for which I need to automate the build and I am trying to choose between NAnt and MSBuild.

Which one should I use?

Which one has better functionality, including support for svn?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

you should read this:

[NAnt or MSBuild, which one to choose and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476163/nant-or-msbuild-which-one-to-choose-and-when)

Answer (score 3):

Why not both? You should be able to start MSBuild from NAnt.

Answer (score 3):

If you have TFS and use a more strict microsoft approach, then I would use MsBuild since it's naturally embedded in the building process.

If you are taking a more open source approach such as TeamCity, CruiseControl, then NAnt may be better.

Comment: Just for info, TeamCity works happily with MSBuild -- we use this combination for our CI builds.

Comment: I agree, and you can call NAnt and MsBuild from each other. I want to show there are "MS approaches" and "Open Source alternatives".