# Putting together a multiproject build script

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nant

I am new to build scripts and need some help putting together a script for a multiple project solution. I currently have just the one project but I need to include other projects, including my test project, so that I can successfully build them all, in the right order.

1) How do you specify order of compilation in the script?
2) How do you group projects together, in order, for build? 
3) When doing a build for production, do you build a solution file or do you just build individual projects? 
4) Are build scripts really necessary(especially when you are using a tool like Visual Studio and no external resources)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Access Report Build Script" default="build" basedir=".">
    <description>Project Build File.</description>
    <property name="debug" value="true" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="fileName" value="BReportSuite" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="Main" value="BReportMain" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="ReportDisplay" value="BReportDisplay" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="ReportRecord" value="BReportRecord" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="ReportAccount" value="BReportAccount" overwrite="false" />

    <target name="clean" description="clean up generated files">
        <delete file="${fileName}.exe" failonerror="false" />
        <delete file="${fileName}.pdb" failonerror="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="compile source">
        <echo message="${fileName}"  />
        <csc target="exe" output="${fileName}.exe" debug="${debug}">
            <sources>
                <include name="${fileName}.cs" />
                <include name="${ReportDisplay}.cs" />
                <include name="${ReportRecord}.cs" />
                <include name="${ReportAccount}.cs" />
            </sources>
        </csc>
    </target>
    </project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nant or MSBuild, which one to choose and when?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476163/nant-or-msbuild-which-one-to-choose-and-when)

Answer (score 0):

Build scripts come in handy when you want to automate things.

For example, if you want to use Continues Integration you want to build your code each time someone checks new code in. This can't be done by just firing up Visual Studio and executing a build manually. 
Also for deployment scenarios, having an automated script is a must. You don't want manual steps in your deployment process that can be forgotten.

The easiest thing to do is just use a solution file that specifies the projects to build. If you configure it with the necessary projects and references and specify a configuration to deploy (release or staging for example) you can configure a lot of settings within Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you please give me a resource to help me accomplish this, I mean use the solution file, and configure it with the necessary objects and references.

Comment: Using a solution file for a build project is no different then how you use them now in Visual Studio. Here is some info on MSBuild http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx If you look at the end of the page you will see that the use a sln file as a parameter.